# arcore the displaying image is perpendicular to the plane

Tags: arcore

This is what I want ->

[image]

Here some importants part of code,  I want to display the author of the book on top of the book but as you see displaying image perpendicular to the book. Help me,  this is what I got ->

[image]

```
  private void OnUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime){
                    Frame frame=arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
            
                    Collection<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages=frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);
                    for(AugmentedImage augmentedImage: augmentedImages){
                        
                        if(augmentedImage.getTrackingState()== TrackingState.TRACKING ){
                            
                            if(augmentedImage.getName().equals("arimage") && shouldAddModel){
                                placeObject(arFragment,
                                        augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()),
                                        Uri.parse("author.jpg"));
                                shouldAddModel=false;
                            }
                    }}
                }
        
          private void placeObject(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor, Uri model){
                ViewRenderable.builder().
                        setView(this,R.layout.lol)
                        .setVerticalAlignment(ViewRenderable.VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM)
                        .build()
                        .thenAccept(viewRenderable -> addNodeToScene(fragment,anchor,viewRenderable))
                        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage())
                                .setTitle("Error!");
                        AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                        return null;
                        });
            }
    
      private void addNodeToScene(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor, ViewRenderable viewRenderable) {
    
            AnchorNode anchorNode=new AnchorNode(anchor);
    
            anchorNode.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        
            TransformableNode node=new TransformableNode(fragment.getTransformationSystem());
        
            node.setRenderable(viewRenderable);
    
            node.setParent(anchorNode);
            fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
            node.select();
    
        }
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the issue?

Comment: hey dude, i edited the question and i added one more image about what i want. I hope it is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple local rotation of the node should do the trick.Once you have set the parent of the node as this.

```
 node.setParent(anchorNode);
 node.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0, 0, 1f), 180));
 fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
```

Play around with the values of the Quaternion. You should get it.

Comment: thanks dude. I have tried the same code on anchorNode before that was my mistake :)

Comment: Glad this helped!